# Installing UniTime to Xampp and I can't run or install the schema.sql in xampp

Tags: mysql, schema

I'm new to mysql, could someone give me the steps on how to run schema.sql to install unitime? the codes are given:`mysql -uroot -p -f <schema.sql` but as I try to execute it I get an error saying,  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -uroot -p -f

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax should be `mysql -u root -p -f < schema.sql`. The error occurred due to the spacing between the "-u" and "root"